# Marketing Channel Flow Map

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have data on all marketing engagements (links clicked, etc), their 'marketing channel', and their 'engagement position".

Engagement position are the following: first touch [first time they ever engage with us], lead create [when they form-fill and give us enough info], opportunity create [the engagement that happened right before an opportunity was created], and closed won [the engagement that happened right before they signed and purchased].

what i want to do is take these 'paths' through our marketing channel, and create a flow map which will map all the possible marketing paths someone has taken.

the data i have contains ID of the engagement, channel, and position like such:

```
______________________________
| id  |  channel  | position |
| 1   | direct    | FT       |
| 1   | SEM       | LC       |
| 1   | email     | OC       |
| 1   | video     | CW       |
______________________________
```

That would be an example of one prospects 'marketing path' and i have a couple hundred thousand of those unique paths. This particular lead would have gone direct > SEM > email > video -- and this would be 1 path.

I'd like to map this out by having the channels be the 'destinations' and the positions determine the order of the movement with the most common path being the boldest (or brightest) and the least common being the least bold (or flattest color)--probably done in ggplot2

I understand this is a bit broad, but i have very very limited experience in visualizing a 'mapping' type of data set, so i dont even know which packages would be useful to me.

I am using R

Comment: So, the positions are always in that order, and the channels can be at any position? Seems like a sankey graph could work. There are several options for making them in R, one is: `networkD3::sankeyNetwork()`

Comment: @AlexP yes--a contact will always have a path in order of FT, LC, OC, CW--however it is possible for the same engagement to be tagged with 2 or more positions; for example if a contact just watched a video, and that was all they did, the video would get all 4 positions.

Comment: hm... so position is an ordered factor... seems like this could be done with ggplot, if each line is very transparent, then the more common paths would show up as darker/more saturated. Sankey diagram would map the number of prospects on each path to the width of the path, which could be interpreted more precisely.

Comment: yeah im not sure if the Sankey would be best--i've seen similar graphs that are more like networks with the most common paths with the thickest bands--i think i saw it recently in most common passes in basketball where it'd map the occurances of player X to Y and Y to Z to see the most common path of how the ball ends up in a players hand.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that example? Seems to me the basketball passes graph is unordered (players can pass back and forth) and can be represented with 2 variables (1 variable for each possible pass, and 1 variable for the number of passes). This case, on the other hand, looks like 3 variables: position, channel, and count; but I'm probably not expressing this correctly. I'm imagining positions along one axis, channels along the other axis, and the count of each path represented with saturation or line weight.

Comment: https://flowingdata.com/2012/12/12/statistical-network-of-basketball/

this is sort of an example of what i'd want--essentially replace the player positions with my marketing channels.

edit: actually here is a better example: https://visual.ly/blog/the-power-of-sports-data-visualizing-passes-between-nba-players-offers-new-game-insights/

Comment: In that case, seems like you can you can drop position, and structure the data in terms of movement from one channel to another. If a single channel is used repeatedly, then there could be a loop arrow. But the first step would be to restructure the data, because in this bball example, there is no ordered variable to display. The columns should be ID, FromChannel, ToChannel.  I still think you really want a sankey diagram to show the progression along your marketing positions, but I'll stop trying to convince.

Comment: @AlexP no i totally want to keep the order component--it is very important to capture that, as some channels are the 'top of funnel' channels that get new leads, and there are channels that really work to progress later stages. I will look into the Sankey for sure--just thought there might be a way to get to it a bit differently as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a try using ggplot. First, make some example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl1 <- tibble(
  id=1:100, 
  channel = sample(c("direct", "SEM", "email", "video"),
                   size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.1,.2,.3,.4)),
  position = "1-FT")
tbl2 <- tibble(
  id=1:100, 
  channel = sample(c("direct", "SEM", "email", "video"),
                   size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.2,.1,.3,.4)),
  position = "2-LC")
tbl3 <- tibble(
  id=1:100, 
  channel = sample(c("direct", "SEM", "email", "video"),
                   size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.3,.2,.1,.4)),
  position = "3-OC")
tbl4 <- tibble(
  id=1:100, 
  channel = sample(c("direct", "SEM", "email", "video"),
                   size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.4, .3,.2,.1)),
  position = "4-CW")

tbl= bind_rows(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4)
```

Then, make an example graph:

```
ggplot(tbl, aes(x=position, y=channel, group=id)) +
  geom_line(alpha=.1, size=3)
```

I think it would be cooler to vary the size by the count; another option would be to use a color scale with the count. Here, I'm using a single alpha value as a hack for a scale.

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! this is exactly what i was looking for. From this i can manipulate my dataset and use this--seriously thanks a ton!

Comment: Great, if it answers your question, click that check mark to call it answered

Comment: Hey Alex, how would i go about using a color scale based on the frequency of each path?

Comment: Hmmm... could either make a frequency table of the marketing pathways and build a graph with that, or use 'stat=count' somewhere in the graph code... I bet if you ask another question specifically on that, you'd get a better answer. If no one else answers it, I will myself later tonight or tomorrow